# what is the best numerical precision in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was wondering, how I can get the best precision on ruby. Someone told me that the best precision is probably between 0 and 1, because as you go into larger numbers the step increases as well.

I suppose a way to find out would be to know what the minimum float number is and what the next float number, then the precision would be the difference, right? If I'm correct how could I do this on ruby?

I am not sure how to use this http://ruby.wikia.com/wiki/Float to find that information.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of significant digits, the precision is the same, regardless of scale. That is, if you scale your range from [0.0, 1000.0]  down to [0.0, 1.0] just by dividing numbers in the natural range by 1000.0, this will have no discernible effect on the precision of your range. In fact, a larger range will have marginally greater precision since it fully contains the smaller range.

As for discovering the absolute precision, you have two problems:

1. The absolute precision depends on the magnitude, which varies "infinitely" within the range [0, 1] (lim<sub>*x*→0</sub> log(*x*) = –∞). So there is no one precision for numbers in that range. You can only derive absolute precision at a given point in the range.
2. The common technique for discovering the minimum step — known as the ulp — is to interpret the bit-representation of the float as an integer, increment it by one, and reinterpret the result as a float. Ruby doesn't, AFAIK, let you do this.

There is, however, an iterative solution. Simply add 1.0 to the number and subtract (`(x + 1.0) - x`). If the difference is zero, double the addend (`(x + 2.0) - x`) and repeat until the difference is non-zero. Otherwise, halve the addend (to 0.5) and repeat until the difference is zero. Whenever you stop, the lowest addend that produces a non-zero difference is the ulp. (I described this from vague memory, so it might be NQR.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use class [`Rational`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Rational.html) - it stores non-integer numbers as fraction of two `Integer`s, which (as far as I know) will be automatically converted to `Bignum`, when need.

Answer (score 1):

The [Flt](https://github.com/jgoizueta/flt) ruby library provides arbitrary floating point precision.